# What is the use of GAL(Global Address Link)

Tags: email

What is the use of Global Address Link(Global address book) used in exchange server.
I want the practical use case scenario example.

Answer (score 2):

GAL stands for Global Address List and it's practical purpose is to allow users to find email recipients in the Exchange organization.